# How to refresh DataTables plug-in for jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, jquery-plugins, datatables

The requirements are:

Display radio buttons that filter the table results.

I'm at the very edge of this functionality working correctly, but I can not figure out how to make the DataTable reload.  After the onclick executes, the client correctly retrieves the data from the server, but I continue to get DataTable runtime errors when attempting to refresh.  The image below returns the correct data in JSON format after the Recommended radio button is clicked:

[image]

**View.vbhtml**

```
@Imports Project.Domain.Models
@Imports Project.Web.ViewModels
@ModelType VaccineViewModel
@Code
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
End Code
@section Styles
   @Styles.Render("~/StylesWithDataTables")
End Section

@section scripts
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app_base = '@Url.Content("~/")';
  </script>
  @Scripts.Render("~/ScriptsWithDataTables")
  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/customajax/vaccine.index.js")
End Section

<div class="page-content">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          @Html.Partial("_GenericMessage")
    </div>
</div>
<div class="portlet box green">
    <div class="portlet-title">
        <div class="caption">
            List
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-body form">
        <div class="form-body">
            <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <a class="btn-sm btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("Add", "Vaccine")"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add New </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label>
                        <input checked type="radio" value="VFC" group="filter" data-filter="1"> VFC
                        <input type="radio" value="Non-VFC" group="filter" data-filter="2"> Non-VFC
                        <input type="radio" value="Recommended" group="filter" data-filter="3"> Recommended
                        <input type="radio" value="Non-Recommended" group="filter" data-filter="4"> Non-Recommended
                        <input type="radio" value="Active" group="filter" data-filter="5"> Active
                        <input type="radio" value="Inactive" group="filter" data-filter="6"> Inactive
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="portlet light portlet-fit portlet-datatable ">
                            <div class="portlet-body">
                                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Vaccine/_Vaccines.vbhtml", New AjaxVaccineFilterViewModel() With {.Vaccines = Model.Vaccines})
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PartialView.vbhtml**

```
@Imports Project.Domain.Models
@Imports Project.Web.ViewModels
@ModelType AjaxVaccineFilterViewModel

<div class="tablecontainer">
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column" id="sample_4">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <th> Vaccine </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Code
            For Each item As Vaccine In Model.Vaccines
            @<tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td> <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Vaccine", New With {Key .id = item.VaccineId})" class="btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</a></td>
                <td> @item.VaccineAbbreviation.ToUpper </td>
            </tr>
            Next
        End Code
    </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

**vaccine.index.js**

```
$(function () {
// Someone has clicked one of the filter radio buttons
 $('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
    var o = {};
    o.filter = $(this).data("filter");

    // Make a viewModel instance
    var viewModel = new Object();
    viewModel.Filter = o.filter;

    //Ajax call to post the viewModel to the controller
    var strung = JSON.stringify(viewModel);

   $.ajax({
        url: app_base + 'Vaccine/ReloadIndex',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: strung,
        success: function (data) {
            //$('.tablecontainer').html(data);
            //$('#sample_4').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            oTableReq = $('#sample_4').DataTable();
            oTableReq.destroy();
            try {
                oTableReq = $('#sample_4').DataTable({
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    responsive: false,
                    //"autoWidth": false,
                    "scrollX": true,
                    data: data,
                    columns: [
         {
             "data": "VaccineId", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                 return '<a class="btn-sm btn-primary" href="/Vaccine/Edit/' + data + '">Edit</a>';
             }
         },
        { "data": "VaccineAbbreviation", "autoWidth": true }
                    ]
                });
            } catch (exception) {
                message(exception, "Attention", "error");
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            ShowUserMessage("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
        }
    });
 });
});
```

**VaccineController.vb**

```
<HttpGet>
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim viewModel As New VaccineViewModel
    viewModel.Vaccines = _vaccineService.GetAllVaccines()
    Return View(viewModel)
End Function

<HttpPost>
Function ReloadIndex(ByVal viewModel As AjaxVaccineFilterViewModel) As JsonResult
    Dim allVaccines As New List(Of Vaccine)
    allVaccines = _vaccineService.GetAllVaccines()
    'filter with client request (which filter?)
    Dim filteredVaccines As New List(Of Vaccine)
    If viewModel.Filter = "1" Then
       filteredVaccines = allVaccines.Where(Function(x) x.VFC.ToLower = "yes").ToList()
    ElseIf viewModel.Filter = "2" Then
       filteredVaccines = allVaccines.Where(Function(x) x.VFC.ToLower = "no").ToList()
    ElseIf viewModel.Filter = "3" Then
        filteredVaccines = allVaccines.Where(Function(x) x.Recommend.ToLower = "yes").ToList()
    ElseIf viewModel.Filter = "4" Then
         filteredVaccines = allVaccines.Where(Function(x) x.Recommend.ToLower = "no").ToList()
    ElseIf viewModel.Filter = "5" Then
         filteredVaccines = allVaccines.Where(Function(x) x.Active.ToLower = "yes").ToList()
    ElseIf viewModel.Filter = "6" Then
         filteredVaccines = allVaccines.Where(Function(x) x.Active.ToLower = "no").ToList()
    Else
         'should not reach this condition
    End If
    'update viewModel
    viewModel.Vaccines = filteredVaccines
    Return Json(viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

**ViewModel**

```
Public Class AjaxVaccineFilterViewModel
    Public Property Vaccines As New List(Of Vaccine)
    Public Property Filter As String
End Class
```

The [DataTables](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38969/reload-refresh-table-after-event) website had an example that appears to be a solution, but I could not get the datatable I implimented to refresh.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=sample_4 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1   and this results from after success in my .js file     $('#sample_4').DataTable().ajax.reload();

Comment: Pls add code where you initialize datatable and where you reload. Thanks

Comment: I added the View which calls the partial view and httpget in the controller.

Comment: I'm not seeing any datatables initialisation code.  It looks like you're creating the table manually on page load (then presumably applying the plugin), but then trying to do the filtering using the datatables API. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, manually populate table with my Model, the use DataTables style.  Search textbox works fine.  My goal is to reload the Model and refresh the table id=sample_4

Comment: The datatables solution you've linked to works because that example is loading json data using the API, so `ajax.reload()` works by simply refreshing the underlying json data. Your POST and GET are both manually creating the table (ie not using the API) so there is no underlying data to refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$.ajax({
    url: app_base + 'Vaccine/ReloadIndex',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: strung,
    success: function (data) {
        var vaccines = data.Vaccines,
            table = $('#sample_4').DataTable();

        table.destroy();

        try {
            oTable = $('#sample_4').DataTable({
                "aLengthMenu": [[15, 30, 60, 120, -1], [15, 30, 60, 120, "All"]],
                "bProcessing": true,
                responsive: false,
                "scrollX": true,
                "aaData": vaccines,
                "columns": [
                 {
                     vaccines: "VaccineId",
                     render: function (vaccines, type, Vaccine) {
                         return '<a class="btn-sm btn-primary" href="/Vaccine/Edit/' + Vaccine.VaccineId + '">Edit</a>';
                     }
                 },
                 {
                    vaccines: "VaccineAbbreviation",
                    render: function (vaccines, type, Vaccine) {
                        return Vaccine.VaccineAbbreviation;
                    }
                 }]
            });
        } catch (exception) {
            alert(exception, "Attention", "error");
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
    }
});
```

Comment: I implemented what you suggested and received the error, "table id=sample_4 - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column1."  Do you have a reference to the code snippet that can guide me in more detail besides datatables.net?

Comment: Hi William, you are close to solving my problem.  My data comes back successfully and I can see it with Chrome>Sources tab and breakpoint.  Do I need to destroy the current table and create a new datatable?

Comment: Hi,Yes, destroy the actual instance of datatable,  I used this way when i update the data using AJAX, because reload never works for me.

Comment: Hi William, on success my viewmodel comes back as:  data = Object {Vaccines: Array(71), Filter: "5"}  How would I reference an index within the Vaccines array?  Also, I'm attempting to rebuild the columns.  Will you review my updated answer and advise?

Comment: updated question, not updated answer.  And btw, I'm not strongly type my table anymore and using ajax to load with $(document).ready(function () { and "type": "get",

Comment: Hi William, I updated your code that helped me get to the answer of my question.

Answer (score 0):

In official [forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38969/reload-refresh-table-after-event) said:

```
$('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```